# Function for Centering Not Working When Browser Resized By Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I wrote a jquery function that centers an inline-block element of unknown width every time the page is resized or when it loads. It does this by calculating the width of the element, then getting the width of the page, and setting the left margin of the element to be the page width - the element width / 2. This works, unless the page is resized by pushing the button at the top or the browser that toggles full screen.

I can't think of why this isn't working, but it seems like the page isn't resetting the left-margin when the page is resized in that manner. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the code.

```
$.fn.center = function() {

    this.each(function() {
        $(this).css("display", "inline-block");

        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        var elementWidth = $(this).width();

        if ((pageWidth - elementWidth) > 0) {
            $(this).css("margin-left", ((pageWidth - elementWidth) / 2) + "px");
        }
    });

    return this;
};
```

It is called on document.ready(), window.load(), and window.resize().

Here is a screen shot of proper behaviour.

[image]

Again, this works when the page loads and when it is resized by the handle.

Here is the improper behaviour which happens when the page is resized by the toggle full screen button in the browser.

[image]

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this behaviour?

Thanks so much!

Edit: I think it is a problem with my resize function. The page is registering that it has been resized but the elements arent centered properly unless the page is resized by dragging the handle. I wonder why it won't work when the page is toggled...

Comment: Does your center function get called when you "resize the browser by pressing a button"? Maybe your function is all right but it simple does not get triggered.

Comment: Which browser do you have this problem in? Could we get a demo?

Comment: @Capricorn, it gets called whenever the browser is resized at all using $(window).resize();.

Comment: @SomeGuy, I am having the problem on the most recent firefox.http://jsfiddle.net/JLMw5/

Comment: Is there any reason to not set the style of `header` to `text-align: center;` and get rid of all your javascript? That's kind of the point of `inline-block`.

Comment: @Khan , yes because I am using this same function on many other elements which that particular solution wouldnt work for. An example is lower on the page I have fixed width tiles which float next to eachother, and I want their container centered without centering each tile.

Comment: @user1472065 In that case you need to set `text-align: center;` on `body` but it works just fine when `#textHolder` has `display: inline-block;`. You can also set the left and right margins to `auto` because that container has a fixed width. You won't have any problems with resizing and orientation changes when you stick to CSS instead of trying to hook into javascript events.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
   console.log('resize!');
});
```

Which jQuery and Browser are you using?

If you are using Firefix I think it could take more ticks to realize the resize. So maybe debouncing or triggering your script after a timeout could solve the problem?

Debounce example:
http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Or you could try something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log('resize');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('later resizing');
  }, 150);
});
```

It could depends to your firefox version. Maybe that issue is related to that topic and should work with a timer? You snipped works fine at FF22

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment. Did you mean to post it as an answer? (OP already said he's using the resize event, and you can see that he is in the demo)

Comment: The most recent jQuery hosted by Google and the latest firefox. and it does work when it is resized by dragging the page, but not by the toggle full screen button at the top of the browser.

Comment: I need to have more than 50 rep to comment the OP :( I tried that first

Comment: I tried adding the timer and the problem remained. :/

Comment: @rayryeng okay, sorry. I thought it might be a possible solution. I searched for a reported issue and a possible workaround and pasted it. But in future I will pay attention to what I write.

Comment: @fortiZ - I improperly flagged it.  Sorry about that!